# How to connect Android Web Apps to a Django development server on an Android USB device

Tags: django, android-webview

I have a python3 application running on Django `127.0.0.1:8000` and I want to access it via an Android Webview Application on an actual Android device not an AVD or Genymotion VM.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities:

1. Deploy your Django app to the server.
2. Run this command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. Now your Django app will work on `127.0.0.1:8000` and in your local network on your IP for example: `192.168.1.123:8000`

If you will choose option 2 remember that your phone with android app needs to be on the same network as Django app.